# Elasticsearch NodeJS : Cannot return properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to return the results from an elasticsearch query. This is my webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#ping-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var val;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:6002/esPingTest',
        success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        alert("Yay");
        val=data;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = val;
        },
        error: function(){
        alert("Nay");
        }
    });


});
});
 </script>
<body>


<center>
<button id='ping-button'>Ping</button>
<br><br>
<p id="demo"></p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

so i have a button, and when i click on it, its supposed to go to the `esPingTest` method.

Here is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cfenv = require('cfenv');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port = (process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000);
var host = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');

// Create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.use(express.static('elastic'));

var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

//start server on the specified port and binding host
var server = app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {

      console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
    })

app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})


app.post('/esPingTest', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {

   console.log("Ping");
   docs = getEsDocs()
   console.log(docs)
   res.end(JSON.stringify(docs));
})

function getEsDocs()
{
    var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
    var client = elasticsearch.Client({
      host: 'localhost:9200',
      log: 'trace'
    });

    client.ping({
      // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout
      requestTimeout: Infinity,

      // undocumented params are appended to the query string
      hello: "elasticsearch!"
    }, function (error) {
      if (error) {
        console.trace('Elasticsearch cluster is down!');
        return "Error:Elasticsearch cluster is down!"
      } else {
        console.log('All is well');
        ff = getmeres(client);
        console.log("ping")
        console.log(ff)
        return ff
        //alert("YAY");
      }
    });

    function getmeres(client)
    {

        var xox =
        client.search({
              index: 'researchtest',
              body: {

                      "aggs": {
                        "docs": {
                          "terms": {
                            "field": "DocumentID"
                          }
                        }
                      }

              }
            }, function (error, response) {
                if (error) {
                    console.trace('Search query failed');
                    return "Error:Search query failed"
                  } else {
                    console.log('All is well');
                    d=response;
                    console.log("getmeres");
                    x=showdocs(d);
                    console.log("inner xo is"+xo);
                    var xo=x;
                    console.log("inner xo is"+xo);

                  }
            });
        console.log("outer xox is"+xox);
        return xox;
    }


    function showdocs(d){
        da=d.hits.hits
        var docs=[]
        for (i=0;i<da.length;i++)
        {   
            docs.push(da[i]["_source"]["DocumentID"]);
        }
        console.log("showdocs")
        console.log(docs)
        return docs;
    }

}
```

so i am calling the `showdocs()` function from inside the else condition of the `client.search` function

at the end i do not see any value returned as a result of `return xo`

here is the result i get

```
getmeres
showdocs
[ '12',
  '12',
  '23' ]
inner xo is[object Object]
inner xo 12,12,23
```

how do i get the value of xo back after the assignment `xo=x`?

why did the last `console.log("outer xox is"+xox);` not get printed at all?

i cant figure out how to return my result back to my webpage

**Edit**

Thanks @peteb for the answer. now here is my call

```
var ff =  getmeres(client, function getmeresResult(err, result){
              if (err) return err;
              console.log("Got res "+result);
              return result;          
            });
        console.log("ping")
        console.log(ff)
        return ff;
```

and the `getmeres` is as you had advised. Now i get

showdocs
    [ '12',
      '12',
      '23' ]
    Got res 12,12,23

which is great! but it still does not assign the value back to `ff`. I need to return `ff` back to `getEsDocs`

should i call `getEsDocs` in the same way as `getmeres`? with a callback? if so, will the following call work

```
docs = getEsDocs(function getDocResult(err, result){
      if (err) return err;
      console.log("Got doc "+result);
      return result;          
    })
   console.log(docs)
   res.end(JSON.stringify(docs));
```

**Almost there**

thanks again, i think i am nearly there

here is my first call

```
getEsDocs(function getDocResult(err, result){
      if (err) return err;
      console.log("Got doc "+result);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
      return result;          
    })
```

here is my second call

```
function getEsDocs(callback)
{
    var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
    var client = elasticsearch.Client({
      host: 'localhost:9200',
      log: 'trace'
    });

    client.ping({
      // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout
      requestTimeout: Infinity,

      // undocumented params are appended to the query string
      hello: "elasticsearch!"
    }, function (error) {
      if (error) {
        console.trace('Elasticsearch cluster is down!');
        return "Error:Elasticsearch cluster is down!"
      } else {
        console.log('All is well');
        return callback(null, getmeres(client, function getmeresResult(err, result){
              if (err) return err;
              console.log("Got res "+result);
              return result;          
            }));
      }
    });
```

it still prints

```
showdocs
    [ '12',
      '12',
      '23' ]
    Got res 12,12,23
```

what am i missing?

**Nearly**

so this is what i have, as you suggested

```
app.post('/esPingTest', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {

   console.log("Ping");
   getEsDocs(function getEsDocsResult(err, result) {
        if (err) return res.status(400).json(result);
        console.log("Got doc"+result)
        return res.status(200).json(result); 
      });

});

function getEsDocs(callback)
{
    var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
    var client = elasticsearch.Client({
      host: 'localhost:9200',
      log: 'trace'
    });

    client.ping({
      // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout
      requestTimeout: Infinity,

      // undocumented params are appended to the query string
      hello: "elasticsearch!"
    }, function (error) {
      if (error) {
        console.trace('Elasticsearch cluster is down!');
        return "Error:Elasticsearch cluster is down!"
      } else {
        console.log('All is well');
        return callback(null, getmeres(client, getmeresResult));
        function getmeresResult(err, result)
        {
              if (err) return err;
              console.log("Got res "+result);
              return result;          
            }
      }
    });


}
```

but i still dont see the final return! can you see anything that is wrong?

so basically this return

```
if (err) return err;
              console.log("Got res "+result);
              return result;
```

does not work!

Comment: Most likely has to do with the lack of context. Maybe provide an idea of what the `client` object is along with the `search` method

Answer (score 1):

Your final `console.log("outer xox is"+xox);` is not getting fired because it is executing immediately after calling `client.search()` since that call is async and won't block execution from continuing within that function. `xox` will be `undefined` when that happens and since `console.log()` won't print if what it's trying to print is concatenated with `undefined`.

Your current implementation of `getmeres()` is going to always return `undefined` because you're returning from outside the callback instead of handling the result of `client.search()` and then returning that value back to the caller from within the callback.

You can get the value out of `getmeres()` by taking a callback function as a parameter and returning the callback with the result. See the below example with an error first callback being taken as the second parameter of `getmeres()`.

```
function getmeres(client, callback) {
  client.search({
    index: 'researchtest',
    body: {
      "aggs": {
        "docs": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "DocumentID"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, function (error, response) {
    if (error) return callback(error, null); // returns the callback with the error that happened

    return callback(null, showdocs(response));  // returns the result of showdocs(response)
});
```

Example of calling `getmeres()` with the callback as a second param

```
getmeres(client, function getmeresResult(err, result) {
  if (err) return err;

  return result;          
});
```

`var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');`, `require()` statements are synchronous and you shouldn't be places this inside getEsDocs because everytime this route is hit, you will block all operations being handle by the main thread running your express server

Get the value back to the route:

```
app.post('/esPingTest', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  getEsDocs(function getEsDocsResult(err, result) {
    if (error) return res.status(400).json(result);

    return res.status(200).json(result); 
  });
});

function getEsDocs(callback) {
  var client = elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
  });

  client.ping({
    // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout
    requestTimeout: Infinity,
    // undocumented params are appended to the query string
    hello: "elasticsearch!"
  }, function (error) {
      if (err) return callback(error, null);

      return callback(null, getmeres(client, getmeresResult));

      function getmeresResult(err, result) {
        if (err) return err;

        return result;          
      });
});
```

Comment: nope its the inner one that executes. i changed it to console.log("inner xo is"+xo); for inner and console.log("outer xo is"+xo); for outer

Comment: @AbtPst can you update your code to show which ones were updated? You have a large number of log statements

Comment: @AbtPst updated with `getmeres()` example taking callback.

Comment: thanks, but now it says reference error callback is not defined

Comment: @AbtPst You need to actually pass a function to that parameter for getmeres to call with the results. See my answer with the example callback handler for getemeres(). So in `getEsDocs()` you'll need to call `getmeres()` with a callback handler that can return `ff` where `ff` is is defined outside the callback handler scope of `client.ping()`

Comment: wait, so i need to do ff=getmeres(client, function getmeresResult(err, result) {
  if (err) return err;

  return result;          
});

Comment: this should be the actual call

Comment: @AbtPst you can just return in front of `getmeres()` and I believe you'll need one in front of `client.ping()`

Comment: thanks! please see the edit. i still need to go one level up

Comment: @AbtPst Then just add a callback from your route into `getEsDocs()` so you can return the result out after `getEsDocs()` is done. Right now I imagine your route is immediately returning without waiting for any result. Make sure to place your `return res.send()` statement in the callback handler for the `getEsDocs()` result in your route.

Comment: @AbtPst updated response with full route callback scenario

Comment: really appreciate all your help. please see the edit. i am still not getting the final return working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you're using `xo` multiple times. The line that's failing is attempting to reassign the value of `xo` to `x` while you're still inside of a function call that's supposed to be returning a value to `xo`. If you get rid of `var xo =` at the beginning, or change it to a different variable name, you should see it run properly.

Comment: changed the variable names. still the outer console.log shows nothing. and the return does not work. is this the proper way to return. basically, once i have the results from `showdocs`, how do i get them out?